# MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013) not recoginizing keyboard and trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

My girlfriend has a 13-inch Mid 2013 MacBook Air, OS X 10.9.5. Yesterday, the keyboard and the trackpad stopped working. I connected a USB keyboard which works.

I believe it's a software problem because:

- The Power key still works (all the time)
- I can boot up in verbose mode (press Command + V while booting)
- I can do an SMC reset (Shift + Control + Option + Power Up)
- I can do a PRAM reset (Option + Command + P + R + Power Up)

All these things seem to work with the built-in keyboard, but as soon as the login window appears, the keyboard does not work anymore (except the power button).

Are there any more things I could try?
Thanks for your suggestions!

Edit:
I just checked the system.log (why didn't I do that earlier?) and the log is FILLED (like 100 messages per second) with these entries:

```
kernel[0]: Error: AppleHSSPIController::InterruptOccurred Failed to transfer interrupt data with Err (0xe00002eb)
kernel[0]: Error: AppleHSSPIController::doSPITransfer NAK received from device
kernel[0]: Error: AppleHSSPIController::doSPITransfer CRC from device was invalid: computed 0xC03B, received 0x9F7D
```

Comment: Does it work in Safe Boot (boot while holding shift)

Comment: It boots in safe mode (means it did recognize the shift press), but at the login window still nothing works except USB keyboard and mouse.

Comment: The boot process starts with generic machine keyboard. After log in system attempts to use the user specified keyboard layout. Did you repair users permissions and disk permissions ?

Comment: I just updated the whole system to Yosemite. Then I tried to repair the disk permissions using the disk utility and then I reset the user permissions using this method: http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/repair-user-permissions-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Sadly still no luck. Keyboard and trackpad not working.

Comment: If you boot with no USB keyboard, does it show the screen where it suggests changing the batteries in your mouse and keyboard?

Comment: Let me try that.

I just checked the system log and found something, I added that to my question.

Comment: No, if i disconnect the USB keyboard and force-reboot (long power button press) the device it boots up completely normal (but, of course, without working keyboard/trackpad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since someone tried to contact me about this issue (he was having the same problem), I will answer my own question.

In the end I took the MacBook to an Apple Shop where they replaced a ribbon cable which solved the problem. Seems like it was a hardware problem after all.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing for those who have similar problems.
You can fix the problem by changing the Macbook A1502 Trackpad Touchpad Keyboard Flex Cable.

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=A1502+Trackpad+Touchpad+Keyboard+Flex+Cable&ref=nb_sb_noss